# Is there any solution to distinguish read or write in Ubuntu mmap?

Tags: linux, mmap, strace

I'm studying Linux programming, and I have a question about `mmap`.

I'd like to look more detail at a process, by using `strace`.   i've done with it, and I saw a system call called `mmap`. But I couldn't see any flag or other clue whether it was mapped memory for read, for write.

Is there any way to distinguish read or write in `mmap`?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

thanks sincerely

Comment: Strace doesn't show you something like `mmap(NULL,4096,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0)` ? For read-only you'll see `mmap` with `PROT_READ`

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 15.04, if I ran

```
strace -f echo "QQQ"
```

I'll get output

```
mmap(0x7f28bc458000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c0000) = 0x7f28bc458000
mmap(0x7f28bc45e000, 16128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f28bc45e000
...
mmap(NULL, 2919792, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f28bbdcf000
```

PROT_READ  - pages may be read

PROT_WRITE - pages may be written

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: but it is about protection. doesn't it ?

Comment: @user3293627 it is exactly what you want, I believe. Mapping is done on per-page basis, and each page is marked as read, read-write, or other flags. You're writing into this memory using say byte addressable array, but it page is marked as PROT_WRITE, it will be ok

Comment: and i'd like to know. mmaped memory will be written to disk. is this case also distinguished with that prot ? it's because. nowadays a lots of programs use mmap instead of write syscall. all i want to know is which mmap in strace is about file wrtie. sorry i was kind of vague. is it possible ? thanks again